# How to write a multilingual regex validation for Russian + Persian + Chinese + English languages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have finally figured out how to validate inserted  russian text in my  tag by

```
    mask = jQuery.extend({unitprmask:/^\d+(\.\d{1,1})?$/,expressmask:/^\d+(\.\d{1,1})?$/,qtymask:/^\d+(\.\d{1,1})?$/,yourdescdmask:/^[а-яА-Я\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]{1,10}$/,URLmask:/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(.*)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/});
```

But I want to allow users to write in the  in mixed languages " Russian + Persian + Chinese + English". how can I make it happened using regex? what should I add to the above code, I have tried to add a-zA-Z to validate english letters but i wasn't successful. I am actually not able to add other languages, the one I wrote

```
  yourdescdmask:/^[а-яА-Я\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]{1,10}$/
```

will allow Russian text only.

Could you please help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a different regex for each language?

Comment: no, it wouldn't be. There are tons of languages with tons of different  alphabets and punctuation, but I don't know much about unicode support in regex.

Comment: What do you want to allow?  Maybe [Unicode Graphical Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_character#Unicode) is a good starting point.  Some written languages are based on letters and combining marks, but not all.

Comment: Btw, `\p{Cyrillic}` doesn't have the same meaning in JavaScript as in Java -- it's equivalent to `[Cilpry\{\}]`.

Comment: @gpgekko I have tried all the suggestions in there, no one worked for me, and not only the suggestions in stack overflow but I have googled it too, still no luck, I am not that lazy to just post and ask for help, I did try many ways to fix my problem since 8am and now its 11pm dear, but thanks anyway please aster the question and respect others who are trying to help

Comment: @Liath yes I thought so, as I just need English / Russian / Persian / Chinese but how to add other languages to what I have now ?? do you have any idea? appreciated

Comment: You may have more success if you give us the text you're trying to validate and the regex you want modifying... as it stands this is quite vague

Comment: @Liath  there is no fix text here, it's a form validator, yourdescdmask will validate <textarea> html tag. ill add the full code above in the question, please have a look

Comment: I have edited the questions, I hope I was success to make myself clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript **does not support** Unicode Script syntax, such as`\p{Cyrillic}`.
<sub>If you don't believe me, you may check the specification of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). As of 5th edition, it is not supported.</sub>

The only way to do a strict multilingual validation in JavaScript is to list range of characters, e.g. `\uxxxx-\uyyyy`.

The Unicode Script syntax is simply implemented based on the [data file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Scripts.txt) by Unicode Consortium.

Using the Unicode Script syntax directly is convenient and make the code clean. However, you don't know what exactly is matched by the character class. You may use this chance to look at the list of characters and filter out whatever you don't want.

Comment: could you please modify yourdescdmask:/^[а-яА-Я\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]{1,10}$/  to let it accept the mentioned languages? I couldn't find a solution, I will pray you everyday if you can fix it, :)

Comment: @user3150692 Don't make promises that you won't satisfy :)

Comment: @user3150692: I don't know which character Russian/Persian uses. Would you please check the list yourself?

Comment: @HamZa HAHA I'LL DO THAT, I am trying to figure it out for 15H already but no luck yet,

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't know either :>